# Extending the User Model

Tags: python, django

I want to extend the User model with custom fields, but I have a little problem

I started creating a Profiles model, with the extra fields that I want:

"models.py":

```
class Profiles(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    url = models.URLField()
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_avatar')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Then, I made a custom UserCreationForm, and I override the save function with the data that I want in the original User model:

"forms.py":

```
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    url = forms.URLField()
    avatar = forms.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "first_name", "last_name", "email",)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data["first_name"]
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data["last_name"]
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Finally, I made a FormView to create the new user and save the extra data in the custom Profiles model:

"views.py":

```
class SignIn(FormView):
    template_name = 'index/signin.html'
    form_class = UserForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('signin')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        profile = Profiles()
        profile.user = user
        profile.url = form.cleaned_data['url']
        profile.avatar = form.cleaned_data['avatar']
        profile.save()
        return super(SignIn, self).form_valid(form)
```

The first user that I sign in with the UserForm creates correctly and the profile model is created too, but after the second sign in, Django prints this Integrity Error: '(1062, "Duplicate entry '' for key 'mail'")'; creating correctly the user, but no the profile one

Do you have any idea of what I'm doing bad?

Thank you

Comment: have you considered using `AbstractBaseUser` ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Comment: I will chet it, but is a bad idea using the way that I tried?

Comment: Is the DB schema pre-existant ? How has the table User begin `CREATE`'d ? What's the content of the column "email" as stored in the DB for your test user ?

Comment: Yes, it was the problem. I drop the tables and made syncdb and now works properly
By the way, is this a good method or I should use the AbstractBaseUser one?